# Using variable to retrieve array element inside awk statement

Tags: awk, array

Below is the part of the code that is throwing error.

```
for (( p=0; p<${var2}; p++ ))
do

if [[ ${array2[$p]} == *"xyz"* ]]
then
    awk -F" " '{ array3[p]="123" };1' ${array1[$i]}
else
    awk -F" " '{ array3[p]="456" };1' ${array1[$i]}
fi
```

When i run the script in debug mode, i could see that the value of p is not being considered.

```
+ awk '-F ' '{ array3[p]="456" };1' oct.csv
```

I am running the script as `./script.sh` and `/bin/ksh` is the shell used. Please help.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm pretty confident you're after `awk -v "p=$p"`.  But btw, it is much better to post a working example or describe what you are after.  We are just guessing what `var2` or `array2` may contain.

Comment: I am trying to assign array3[p]="123" but since value of p is not getting retrieved, i want to know how to get it where p is a variable.

Comment: @user2568967 You're wanting to assign ${array3[$p]} value to "123" or "456" depending on if ${array2[$p]} is == *"xyz"*, right? But why are you setting a variable inside the awk statement then not using it? Examples of what you want to accomplish with array3 would be helpful. Also as an FYI you don't need to use `-F" "`with  `awk` as it uses space as the field separator by default.

Comment: I am trying to use the variable inside the awk array statement but not sure how to use it since i could not retrieve the value of p. Once it is retrieved, its place will be filled either with 123 or 456.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is wrong:

```
awk -F" " '{ array3[p]="123" };1' ${array1[$i]}
```

`${array1[$i]}` is not a file, so you can't just throw it as first command line argument to `awk`. With variables you'd have to use either `echo $VARIABLE` or here string `<<<` like so

```
awk -F" " '{ array3[p]="123" };1' <<< ${array1[$i]}
```

Second, of all, there is a scope issue. `array3[p]="123"` only exists within `awk` code, so you can't assign anything to an outside of it. What you could do, however, simply do

```
array3[$p]="123"
```

It is also unclear where exactly `$i` comes from in your script. Overall, your question gives us a bit of code but doesn't provide any clues to fully answer your question